# useState not behaving properly and not updating on change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, use-state

So to display a pop-up, I am using a modal but it seems that the `show` state is not changing.

This is the code I have done for the logn From `index.js`

```
const Form = ({ initialState = STATE_SIGN_UP, displayPopUp}) => {
  const [mode, toggleMode] = useToggle(initialState);
  const [display, toggleDisplay] = useToggleDisplay(displayPopUp);

  return (
    <Modal className="modal" show={display}  size="lg">
        <Container pose={mode === STATE_LOG_IN ? "signup" : "login"}>
        <div className="container__form container__form--one">
            <FormLogin mode={mode} toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay} />
        </div>
        <div className="container__form container__form--two">
            <FormSignup mode={mode} toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay}/>
        </div>
        <Overlay toggleMode={toggleMode} mode={mode} />
        </Container>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

So when Form is called at first, `displayPopUp` is set to false and it works.

The Form in `index.js` is called by another componend `header.js` as below.

When I click on the Header Login/Register it's change displayPopUp to `true` as expected.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            anchorEl: null, 
            showLogin: false};
    }
    
    openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
      };
    
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: null })
      };



       render(){
          ...
          return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="header-village" width="100" expand="lg">
            ...
            </Navbar>
            <LoginRegisterForm displayPopUp={this.state.showLogin} onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
            </div>
```

Now, it was working because I was using `displayPopUp` to show or not the modal. but now, I have also to be able to close the modal so, I am passing a callback in the `FormLogin` and `FormSignup` in order to be able to update `display` on click and close the modal.

I have used the class `useToggleDisplay` to make the flip but it's not working.

I saw the `displayPopUp` being assigned to `false` and `true` but display never change or `toggleDisplay`.

This is the code for `toggleDisplay` declared in `useToggleDisplay`

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

export const STATE_SHOW = true
export const STATE_HIDE = false
const useToggleDisplay = initialDisplayState => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(initialDisplayState)

  const toggleDisplay = useCallback(
    () => setDisplay((display) => {
        console.log('display: ' + display)
        return !display; 
    }),
    []
  );
  return [display, toggleDisplay];

export default useToggleDisplay
```

my goal is to be able to control the `show` value from `FormLogin` and `FormSignup` to make sure I can close the modal

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: @HMR thanks a lot. Can you show me in the code  I provided how to do it ? I am newbie so kind of tricky sometimes for me

Comment: @HMR i wasn't able to make it work. can you check my updated description. i am not able to show the modal when clicking

Comment: @HMR So based on your comment below, I was thinking using `displayPopUp` as a way to pass the click from the header as the header contain the menu. set to false to prevent the showing of the modal until I click on `login/register`